# R: Change strip text of effect plot

Tags: r, plot, effects

I have a simple effect plot in R using the effects package. Here is an example:

```
require(effects)
A  <-  rnorm(100)
B  <-  rnorm(100)
C  <-  factor(rep(c("right", "left"), 50))
eff <- effect("B:C", lm(A~B*C))
plot(eff)
```

[image: example]

I want to change the strip text of the panels (in this case C:left and C:right) to any text (eg. text:left). There is an unelegant way to achieve this by changing the data using:

```
names(eff$x)[names(eff$x)=="C"] <- "text"
```

I don't want to change the data though. Also changing the element name restricts me from using spaces or other special symbols. Using the function to change the strip names in plot.eff

```
plot(..., strip = function(...) strip.default(..., strip.names = c(factor.names, TRUE)))
```

gives me an error though ("formal argument "strip" matched by multiple actual arguments") since this seems to be used by the xyplot too.
Is there a way to change the strip text without modifying the data? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78002286/2094893) is how to use a custom `strip` function with `effects`.

Comment: Guess this solves the nearly forgotten open question of mine. Thank you! If you post your comment as an answer instead I will gladly accept it as solution.

Comment: I guess so. Now you will finally be able to sleep at night! :) Regarding the answer, I am afraid the best course of action here will be to mark your question as a duplicate of the newer one (rather than duplicating the answer).