# Is there a way to customise panel titles in an effects plot?

Tags: r, plot, graph, interaction

I have created the plot below to visualize interactions but I was wondering if I can customize the parts of the plot that say *education = College*, *education = Graduate*, *education = High School*.

Code:

```
# Generate example data
set.seed(123)
education <- factor(rep(c("High School", "College", "Graduate"), each = 30))
study_hours <- rep(c(10, 20, 30), each = 10, times = 3)
exam_scores <- rnorm(90, mean = 70, sd = 10)

# Create dataframe
example_df <- data.frame(education, study_hours, exam_scores)
# Fit the model with interaction term
library(glmmTMB)
models_example <- glmmTMB(exam_scores ~ education * study_hours, data = example_df)

# Generate the effects plot for the interaction term
library(effects)
effects_plot_example <- plot(allEffects(models_example, data = example_df))

# Display the plot
print(effects_plot_example)
```

[image]

Examples of what I tried:

1. I attempted to rename the variable to `Educational Level` before plotting but the space gave me this error

```
Error in parse(text = paste("~", paste(extras, collapse = "+"))) : 
  <text>:1:28: unexpected symbol
```

2. I tried several arguments in the `plot`/`allEffects` function like `panel.title` but I can't find which could modify this part of the plot, I am not even sure how this part of the plot is called.

Comment: What do you want your titles to be?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Would the content influence the approach? I would like these titles "Educational Level: College Educational Level: Graduate Educational Level: High School" instead of "education = College education = Graduate education = High School"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `effects:::plot.eff()` directly, it will produce a `plot.eff` object for which you can modify the `strip` function which is used to create the labels you want to change.

```r
library(lattice)
# save the plot object
ef.plot <- effects:::plot.eff(allEffects(models_example, data = example_df)[[1]])

# change the function which draws strips at the top of the panels to a custom one
ef.plot$strip <- strip.custom(
  var.name = 'Educational Level', 
  factor.levels = c('College', 'Graduate', 'High School'),
  strip.names = c(T, T),
  strip.levels = c(T, T),
  sep = ': ')

# draw the plot with the new strip function
ef.plot
```

[image: effects plot with modified labels]